# SendEmail error: You have uncommitted work pending

Tags: callout, exception, spring16

My code works everywhere except in a particular client sandbox. It basically sends an email on insert of a record.

**Pseudo-code in PKG A**

```
trigger on after-insert of recordX
    Messaging.sendEmail(email)
```

**Offending code in sandbox**

```
insert new RecordX
```

The error in this specific sandbox is:

> System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0;
>   first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, You have uncommitted work pending.
>   Please commit or rollback before calling out: []

Here are the last few lines of the logs:

```
16:03:13.395 (431553895)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[39]|mail|Messaging.SingleEmailMessage|true|false
16:03:13.395 (431641669)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[39]|mail|"common.api.soap.wsdl.SingleEmailMessage@51484da"|0x1d47ef24
16:03:13.395 (431647105)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[40]
16:03:13.395 (431662684)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[9]|email|Messaging.SingleEmailMessage|true|false
16:03:13.395 (431707578)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[9]|email|"common.api.soap.wsdl.SingleEmailMessage@51484da"|0x1d47ef24
16:03:13.395 (431712353)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[10]
16:03:13.395 (431761721)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[11]
16:03:13.395 (431812208)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:4
16:03:13.395 (431836983)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[4]|Bytes:5
16:03:13.395 (431853427)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[4]|rt|null|
16:03:13.395 (431858129)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[14]
16:03:13.395 (431859506)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[14]
16:03:13.395 (431887361)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[14]
16:03:13.395 (431942623)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:8
16:03:13.395 (585405722)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[14]|System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out: []
16:03:13.395 (586030977)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[14]|Bytes:163
16:03:13.395 (586074343)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[16]|e|System.EmailException|true|false
16:03:13.395 (586151005)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[16]|e|"common.apex.methods.MessagingStaticMethods$EmailExecutionException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out: []"|0x6406da32
16:03:13.395 (586159529)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[16]
16:03:13.395 (586198500)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[17]|Bytes:159
16:03:13.395 (586206818)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[17]|Bytes:27
16:03:13.395 (586235313)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[17]
16:03:13.395 (586285305)|FATAL_ERROR|System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out: []

Trigger.PKGA.TriggerX: line 14, column 1
16:03:13.395 (586302271)|FATAL_ERROR|System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out: []
```

While [this KB article](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003701) seems to address the issue (albeit indirectly, as I am not doing a callout here) I don't understand the reason for the discrepancy.

Note that sending a simple email through Execute Anonymous works fine.

Comment: Looks like there is callout in between transaction.

Comment: Logs are not showing any callouts. It is breaking right when SendEmail is called.. Also an update here: this issue is only happening in one particular sandbox. It works fine in other sandboxes. So it can't be Spring '16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The email that was being sent was based on a VF template with an attachment component whose controller called getContent() on a SF record. The following Critical Update connects the dots:

[“PageReference getContent() and getContentAsPDF() Methods Behave as Callouts” Critical Update Postponed](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_vf_pagereference_getcontent_cruc.htm)

This update had been activated in this particular sandbox instance, which explains why no other org experienced the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the reason for this error is where a DML statement is performed before a callout. In your case it looks like sending the email is counted as a callout.

You have two options that I see:

1. Send your email and then insert recordX
2. Insert recordX, then make sendEmailViaTrigger() a future / Queueable implementation. Making this method asynchronous will mean that it counts as a separate transaction, avoiding the error.

More info on future methods [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_invoking_future_methods.htm) and more info on the Queueable interface [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm) .

HTH

Comment: Why would it be counted as a callout in one sandbox but not for others? More importantly why would SendEmail count as a callout?! Btw I am only looking for the reason for the discrepancy not the solution/workaround. Thanks!

Comment: Without your code it's hard to say, but if you have multiple triggers on a single object then possibly the order of trigger execution is different on that single sandbox.

Comment: There are no other triggers on insert of recordX. The sequence of events is exactly: insert recordX > trigger on recordX runs and calls SendEmail. According to the debug logs nothing else is happening in between..

Comment: Can you post all the code in question?